# Delphi 7 CRLF clsid registry name read error win32

Tags: delphi, registry, newline

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  Registry.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('\Software\Classes\CLSID\{76468B8C-00A3-4AE0-9081-C1116F67C6F4}\MyValue');
  Edit1.Text := Registry.ReadString('Value1');
  Edit2.Text := Registry.ReadString('Value2');
  Edit3.Text := Registry.ReadString('Value3');
  Registry.CloseKey;
  Registry.Free;
end;
```

I am trying to read the records of a program with this code. I can read other clsid values, but;

[image]

However, there is a CRLF in the record shown in the picture. I can't read it. How can I do it?

Registry files:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{76468B8C-00A3-4AE0-

9081-C1116F67C6F4}\MyValue]
"value1"="...
```

Comment: I trust in a real app you would use `try..finally` to protect the registry object.

Comment: I am pretty sure CLSIDs aren't allowed to contain linebreaks. However, have you tried `'\Software\Classes\CLSID\{76468B8C-00A3-4AE0-'#13#10'9081-C1116F67C6F4}\MyValue'`?

Comment: REGEDIT.EXE also wouldn't manage any keys or values that have `#0` in their name although it's possible to create and read those thru WinAPI.